# how to check an event is fired by simulated actions or manually performed actions

Tags: java, events, event-handling, mouseevent

I want to know is it possible to check an event is generated by another event or manually generated event.In brief suppose we click any button, inside action performed if we write code to generate another event on some other component, how can i get to know which is generated by which.
How can differentiate whether manual or simulated based on event generated????

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        JComponent source  =(JComponent) ae.getSource();
       //this is action for manually clicked event.
        if(source  == button1)
        {
          //this is to generate simulated event.
           exitButton.doClick();
        }
        //this is action for simulated event.
        else if (source == exitButton) 
        {
           System.exit(0);
        }
    }

Comment: Where is the trial code?

Comment: Where's your code? Put some effort in... you haven't even bothered to correctly tag the question. I'm sure there's an event tag or something else that applies here, rather than the non-specific Java tag.

Comment: @bcsb1001 OP seems to be asking for the code in the first place. A proper tag would do no help. It would only invite more users and hence, more downvotes and flags to be closed.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MathewsMathai I was just commenting about the complete lack of effort put in. More tags without an improved question isn't ideal, but a better question without more tags wouldn't be seen.

Comment: @bcsb1001 No offence. I was trying to help the OP and that link was for the OP. You misunderstood me.

Comment: @MathewsMathai You misunderstood me. I was replying to your second comment.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Alright. Got it. Anyway, it's all for the same purpose. A good question and suitable tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could distinguish between your custom events and other events by checking their class type.

```
if (catchedEvent instanceof MyCustomEvent){}
```

If you have several custom events, you could set eventCode in MyCustomEvent class to indicate the event meaning.

[this link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077333/core-java/mr-happy-object-teaches-custom-events.html) may help you too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not at all creating any custom event. If I am not aware of any customevents created by some other. How can I achieve this.???